# jquery form plugin and cakephp 2 - submitting via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, file-upload

I'm attempting to use the jquery form plugin to upload an image via ajax. I want the response to be the filename so that I can show the processes and saved version of the image on the same page that made the request. This seems like it should be easy enough. Although I'm a bit of a newbie with cakephp and jquery, I've been trying to do this for 3 full days now in different ways and have run into road block after road block! Anyway - some code:

I have the following form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Tile', array('type'=>'file', 'action' => 'uploadImage')); ?>
<div id="TileImageUpload">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('upload_image', array('type' => 'file'));?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->button('upload image', array('onClick'=>'$(\'#TileNewtileForm\').ajaxSubmit({target: \'#TileImageUpload\''));?> 
 </div>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

So that allows a user to select an image and it submits to the uploadImage action of the tiles controller:

```
function uploadImage() {
$this->layout = 'ajax';
//process the image in here and save a copy of it, then return the images name
echo 'imagename';   
}
```

What is returned is supposed (according to the tutorials and what I make of the docs) be placed in #TileImageUpload - which is the target div for the response. But actually it just goes to the view for uploadImage which just says imagename. I want the imagename to come back to the same page which made the request, so that I can append the image to the document.

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Any body able to help me out with this? I gave up for a few hours thinking a break would help but I'm getting no-where fast :(

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this plugin:
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

And its CakePHP version:
https://github.com/hugodias/FileUpload